# Row-wise summing for each month in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, group-by

I have the following (simplified) dataframe which contains a date column:

```
Date = c("2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-01")
Values = c(1.123389e+02, 7.975111e+01, 7.782333e+01, 4.643222e+01, 2.625444e+01, 8.565556e+00)
df <- data.frame(Date, Values)
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d"));
```

which is:

```
Date,       Values
2011-01-01, 1.123389e+02
2011-02-01, 7.975111e+01
2012-01-01, 7.782333e+01
2012-02-01, 4.643222e+01
2013-01-01, 2.625444e+01
2013-02-01, 8.565556e+00
```

What I would like to do, is to average the values that correspond to the same month to get the following:

```
Date, Sum
Jan, 216.4167
Feb, 134.7489
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coercing to a real date with `as.Date`, like in the question, keep only the month with `format`. Then aggregate the data.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         Date = format(Date, "%b")) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Values), .by = Date)
#>   Date      Sum
#> 1  jan 216.4167
#> 2  fev 134.7489
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(grp=lubridate::month(as.Date(Date), label=TRUE)) %>% summarise(Values=sum(Values))


# A tibble: 2 × 2
  grp   Values
  <ord>  <dbl>
1 Jan     216.
2 Feb     135.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using dplyr to get the expected output you provided.

First, use mutate to extract the month and year, then group by month, and then use summarize to sum up the values column like this:

```
# Extract month and year from the Date column
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Month = format(Date, "%b"),
         Year = format(Date, "%Y"))

# Group by month and calculate the sum
result <- df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Values)) %>%
  arrange(Month)

# Expected output
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Month   Sum
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Feb    135.
2 Jan    216.
```

This will start with Feb first since it is starts with F which is ahead of J in January. You can use a neat little trick to arrange from January with the month.abb constant like this:

```
result <- df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(Sum = sum(Values)) %>%
  arrange(match(Month, month.abb))

# Expected output
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Month   Sum
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Jan    216.
2 Feb    135.
```

The actual dataframe contains the decimal values, but printing to console cuts them off because of the print formatting. Hope this helps.